# Remove a String Item from a List of Strings

Tags: java, android, string

How do I remove a specific string from a List that contains Strings....

As in:

```
ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();
myStrings.add("Alpha");
myStrings.add("Beta");
myStrings.add("Gama");
.                           //The order can be random 
.
.
.
```

Now , I only have the list myStrings and I don't know which String is at which index. But I know, that I want to display all the strings after removing say "Alpha".

To Summarize , How can I get the strings from a String array after removing a String that I know that array contains , but don't know its index/position.

Comment: iterate over them and implement the logic yourself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use remove :

```
myStrings.remove("Alpha");
```

Note that this would only remove the first occurrence of "Alpha" from your list.

Comment: Its a boolean and does not match my requirement to get the String value.

Comment: @asdec90 It removes "Alpha" from the list. It returns "true" if "Alpha" was found and removed. After you remove it, you can iterate over the list and display the remaining Strings. I was assuming you know how to iterate over a list. The simplest way - `for (String s : myStrings) {...}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean remove(Object o)
```

The above method of ArrayList class will remove the first occurence of **Object o** from the list.

You can do:

```
myStrings.remove("Alpha");
```

It will return **true** if the ArrayList contained the specified element.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have duplicates in the list of String that you also wish to remove?

If so, you can convert the `list` of String into a `set` of String. Then, you can remove strings from the `set` efficiently, convert it back into a `map`.

```
// converting to set will remove duplicates
final Set<String> uniqueStrSet = new HashSet<String>(listOfString);

// remove string from set
uniqueStrSet.remove(strToRemove);

// convert set back to list
list = new ArrayList<String>(uniqueStrSet);
```

Answer (score 2):

if this not work

```
myStrings.remove("Alpha");
```

try this it works fine with me

```
int pos = myStrings.indexOf("Alpha");//Getting string position
myStrings.remove(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with immutable lists which is quite often the case now, you will not be able to use the `remove` method; instead you shall get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Use a Lamda instead:

```
List<String> filteredList = myStrings.stream()
        .filter(toRemove -> !"Alpha".equals(toRemove))
        .toList();
```

That's the idea. It should be adapted to your specific use case.

NB: the `"Alpha".equals(...)` is recommanded by Sonarqube when using litterals. Please don't lash me for it.